# How to dynamically decide to pass a prop to a react component or not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using KeyboardAvoidingView and I want to pass a prop 'behaviour' to it in case the platform is IOS and none in case it's android. I don't wanna write two separate JSX component declarations  for the same. Is there a way to decide to pass a prop or not. Also react-native's docs don't mention any default value for the behaviour props which I could have set conditionally otherwise.

```js
Based on the platform the component should be declared the following way

FOR IOS
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={modalContainer} >
  {this.props.children} //I've lots of children here and they're composed inside of the keyboardavoidingview and i'm not using this.props.children as they're in the same parent component
</KeyBoardAvoidingView>


FOR ANDROID
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={modalContainer} >
  {this.props.children}
</KeyBoardAvoidingView>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can conditionally pass a prop by passing the `value` or `undefined`

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={platform="android"? "padding": undefined} style={modalContainer} >
  {this.props.children}
</KeyBoardAvoidingView>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create a [Higher Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) of KeyboardAvoidingView and pass the platform prop through that.

```
function HOC() {
    return class PlatformSpecific extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
           super(props);
           if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
               this.state = { behavior: "padding" };
           } else this.state = {};
        }
        render() {
            return <KeyboardAvoidingView {...this.props} {...this.state}/>;
        }
    };
}
```

EDIT: Why create an extra HOC? Because it's extendable. You could even pass the component to render and make this HOC an extra usecase for other components.

```
function HOC(ComponentToRender) {
    return class PlatformSpecific extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
           super(props);
           if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
               this.state = { behavior: "padding" };
           } else this.state = {};
        }
        render() {
            return <ComponentToRender {...this.props} {...this.state}/>;
        }
    };
}
```

And use it like so:

```
const KeyboardAvoidingComponent = HOC(KeyboardAvoidingView);
const AnotherPlatformSpecificComponent = HOC(AnotherComponent)
// in render:
<KeyboardAvoidingComponent {...props} />
<AnotherPlatformSpecificComponent {...props} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to be platform specific

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behaviour={Platform.OS == "android" ? "padding" : undefined}  style={modalContainer} >
      {this.props.children} //I've lots of children here and they're composed 
    </KeyBoardAvoidingView>
```

or you have this option obviously.

```
{Platform.OS == "ios" && <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={modalContainer} >
  {this.props.children} //I've lots of children here and they're composed 
</KeyBoardAvoidingView>}


{Platform.OS == "android" && <KeyboardAvoidingView style={modalContainer} >
  {this.props.children}
</KeyBoardAvoidingView>}
```

Comment: I know the latter approach but don't wanna use it as it's clutter the file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing it.

1.

```
{Platform.select({
 ios: () => (
   <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">...</KeyboardAvoidingView>
 ),
 android: () => (
  <KeyboardAvoidingView>...</KeyboardAvoidingView>
 )
})()}
```

2.

```
//keyboard.ios.js

export function Keyboard(props) {
 return (<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
  {props.children}
 </KeyboardAvoidingView>);
}

//keyboard.android.js

export function Keyboard(props) {
 return (<KeyboardAvoidingView>
  {props.children}
 </KeyboardAvoidingView>);
}

// Main.js
import {Keyboard} from "./keyboard";
function Main (props) {
 return (
  <Keyboard>
   <Text>hello</Text>
  </Keyboard>
 );
}
```

Comment: I'd rather avoid doing both as it'll bloat the code. I wanted to know the way of declaring it once and passing the prop based on the condition. Anyway I got the answer, I can send undefined if I don't want it to be set at all